# C++ if statement maximum number of elements

Tags: c++

Given this condition

```
if(statement0 || statement1 ||... || statement n){
  ...
}
```

What is the maximum value of n in C++?

Where I can find this information?

Comment: I doubt there's a restriction how many expressions can appear in a condition.

Comment: Theoretically there's no limit, in practice it depends on the compiler, the computer, the computers operating system, the computers available virtual memory, etc.

Comment: Oh, and it also depends a lot on what your code-reviewers will let you get away with, which will most likely be much less than any other limit.

Comment: .... And how much the keyboard can take

Answer (score 2):

The limit is defined by your implementation. C++14 §B does suggest some recommended minimum quantities for things like maximum line length, maximum program size, maximum number of nested parenthesised expressions ... but there are no exact, standardised constraints in this sense.

It doesn't matter, anyway, because if you go above three or so your code is terrible.

Comment: For example, how can you do a static_assert without a lot of || ?

Comment: @IonutCosminMihai: What??

Comment: for example you have a static assert and you need to check a lot of types in this static assert, how can you do this, you can't use switch or if

Comment: @IonutCosminMihai: _Why_ do you feel you need to check "a lot of types" in an assert? I'm suspicious of a major design problem. You can usually workaround such a problem by writing more `static_assert`s underneath. If you can't because your assertion is a complex, tangled, long mess of interconnected boolean checks, you have a serious problem and need to resolve that before trying to work out how far down the rabbit hole your compiler will permit you to go before calling you out on your nonsense.

Comment: in the static_assert there are several conditions, if one is true, then the assert argument is true, how can I do this without ||?

Comment: @IonutCosminMihai: You can use `||`. You just shouldn't be using more than few of them.

Comment: I don't want to use a lot of ||, but there is no other way, I need the conditions to be checked at compile time and as far as I can see there is no other solution without writing a lot of specialized methods.

Comment: @IonutCosminMihai: Still waiting for you to explain why this is a problem. Just how many conditions do you have?